# VBA loop shapes except one

Tags: excel, vba, loops, shapes

I want to hide all the shapes that are pictures except one
so I want to create a loop for pictures and exclude one that has name of 2 for example
I could only create the loop for all of them I couldn't include the 2nd condition to exclude that one based on name

what I tried:

```
Sub Total()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
x = ws.Shapes.Count

    For i = 1 To x
        If ws.Shapes(i).Type = 13 Then ws.Shapes(i).Visible = False
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `And ws.Shapes(i).Name <> "..."`?..

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the picture below, it shows a chart, two pictures and some shapes that you can rename quickly by accessing the Selection Pane in the Format Tab.

This code will hide all the objects that start with 'Rectangle' except 'Rectangle 2'.

```
Sub HideShapes()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If Left(sh.Name, 9) = "Rectangle" And sh.Name <> "Rectangle 2" Then sh.Visible = False
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This will hide everyshap in the sheet and I have graphs, pictures and different shapes...I want to hide all pictures except one with name 2 other shapes, graphs should stay visible

Comment: Just updated the code and inserted an image to be more simple to understand.

Comment: Thank you @Elio I adjusted it according to my shapes names and it works fine, thank you so much really appreciated

Comment: @mabdelhady, if the answer was useful, you could put a check on it!